# Rotate an image in the image viewer?

Tags: image, uv-image-editor

[image]
For some reason this image I imported is sideways, I think my phone glitched when I took the picture.
Can I rotate it within the image viewer?

Comment: If you're using Windows, you can rotate the image in the OS. Open the folder in Windows to be able to view the directory contents, select the image (Note: you don't *have* to open it, just select it), left click on the image, and two of the choices in the context menu are "Rotate clockwise" and "Rotate counterclockwise".

Answer (score 1):

I would rotate the image in an external program like paint or Photoshop.
CORRECTION

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0Y5Y.png

you can rotate it here.

Comment: That is only for the 3D View background picture, not the Image Viewer, as the poster requested.

Answer (score 1):

for now what can be useful to you within Blender without using another App is in Compositing use this nodes: image, transform and viewer. Then into Layout go to Image Editor and "Browse image to be linked" and choose Viewer Node[image]